# Couchbase Local Server asks for Authentication

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm sending *GET* request at *http://192.168.43.166:4984/grocery-sync/* `{"error":"Unauthorized","reason":"Login required"}` and it asks for Username and Password, I don't know which credentials it's asking as I have not entered any authentication credentials while installing. How do I add these credentials now, if I want to or is there any default credentials to do Authentication?

[image]

Comment: Is this couchdb or couchbase?

Comment: Please refer to [the documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/current/authentication.html)

Comment: I'm working on Couchbase. I got a hack around, where I'm going wrong, Can anyone of you share sync-gateway-config-travelsample.json, which is used in the docs, (https://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/mobile-travel-sample/java/installation/manual.html#sync-gateway).

Comment: What app are you trying out? In your original question, you have grocery-sync app but in the comments are referring to the Travel Sample app. In any case, for the latter, the second step in the instructions in the link that you shared specify where you can find the JSON config. That said, as indicated above, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/current/authentication.html) to understand how authentication works.

Comment: I want it to integrate with my personal application. The JSON file (https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mobile-travel-sample/blob/master/sync-gateway-config-travelsample.json#L37), this line is having some issue. What is the purpose of this line as I have removed it and the Gateway Sync Server is working fine?

Comment: @rajagp I want to implement is that Synchronization and implement basic CRUD operations using Gateway Sync Server and let them persist in Couchbase Server. Can you also tell me how Couchbase Server will interact with back-end server?

Comment: It seems like the sync issue is resolved following the comments in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507786/status-403-sg-wrong-user-while-using-couchbase?noredirect=1#comment101551989_57507786). As far as how to interact with Couchbase Server, you can use one of the [SDKs](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/sdk/overview.html)